# Android - play adaptive bitrate video from Azure Media Services

Tags: android, azure, video, stream, media

I have uploaded some video files to my Azure Media Service with the multi-bitrate MP4 encoding. I have the Media Service set up with one streaming unit and a Premium subscription, so it supports adaptive bitrate streaming.

On my Android app, I use the default [VideoView widget](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/VideoView.html) but it doesn't seem to actually be using adaptive bitrate streaming. How can I make sure it is using adaptive bitrate?

EDIT: we are using the HLSv4 link from Azure Media Service (format=m3u8-aapl)

Answer (score 2):

What kind of streaming protocol are you using exactly? The standard media library in Android is somewhat limited in this regard, so you might wanna take a look at [ExoPlayer](https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer), it supports a much wider range of streaming protocols (like DASH and SmoothStreaming for example)

There's also a [wrapper](https://github.com/brianwernick/ExoMedia) for ExoPlayer, which allows you to more or less use it as a drop in replacement for your VideoView.

Comment: I believe we are using the HLSv4 link from Azure Media Service (format=m3u8-aapl). Is this supported by the default player?

Comment: Probably, but not necessarily very well. Problem with the default Media Player is that it is frozen in time, and historically it did have its issues with Streaming. ExoPlayer can be updated independently of Android, so it's much more likely to work correctly. So instead of trying to debug the default player, you might have better success just trying that instead. At least that's what we did when we had similar issues.